# How to convert Java code snippet into C#

Tags: java, c#-4.0

I'm struggling to understand how to convert this Java code into a C# one.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
public enum Direction {

NORTH(0), EAST(1), SOUTH(2), WEST(3);
private static Map<Integer, Direction> map = new HashMap<Integer, Direction>();

static {
    for (Direction directionEnum : Direction.values()) {
        map.put(directionEnum.directionIndex, directionEnum);
    }
}
```

Comment: That shouldn't be difficult. You will need data structure mapping while you port this code to C#. enum also exists in C# as is. The for loop you are using in your code snippet best maps to foreach keyword as it doesn't involve any counters. For HashMap you should use Dictionary data type.

Comment: @RBT: Thank you for your response.  Should Direction enum ported like this? public enum Direction { NORTH = 0, EAST = 1, ... }

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Comment: BTW the directionIndex that you are inserting into the map - Is that the corresponding integer value of the enum like for NORTH it is 0?

Comment: Yes, directionIndex is the corresponding integer value of the enum type

Comment: You should be good to go then. I've added all the details in my answer. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your ported C# code. Knowledge of `Enum.GetValues(typeof(Direction)` API is the only thing which could have hindered your smooth porting if you don't know it. Hope this helps!

```
        public enum Direction
        {
            NORTH = 0,
            EAST = 1,
            SOUTH = 2,
            WEST = 3
        }

        private static Dictionary<int, Direction> map = new Dictionary<int, Direction>();

        private static void PortJavaCodeToCSharp()
        {
            foreach (var directionName in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Direction)))
            {
                map.Add((int)directionName, (Direction)directionName);
            }    
        }
```

Comment: cool.  Yeah, you are right about the 'Enum.GetValues(typeof(Direction))', I haven't used it before to get the values of an enum type.  Thank you!